# How to find average pay rate by each company in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table called job opening and it has attributes ( company name, opening_available, opening_description, Hourly_Pay) whereby i have 4 rows of data, each with unique companies.

i have been given a query to calculate average pay of each companies
i am confused how to do it..here is my table

```
company name|opening_available|opening_description|Hourly_Pay
 1. Facebook| 4               | Senior programmer | 4.50
 2. Google  | 5               | Web developer     | 5.00
 3. Metropol| 4               | Web Designer      | 6.00
 4. dailybug| 3               | Junior programmer | 7.50
```

Comment: which version of My SQL are you using?

Comment: Average of what? Each row is a different company. Average of the whole table?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: it doesnt specify each row or table.. it just tells to determine the average pay rate based for the respective
companies

Comment: I wanted to calculate all the pay from each company and divide them by number of companies for average..but that seemed wrong

Comment: What exactly is "pay rate"? Do you want to calculate average hourly pay? Or is there some kind of relation you did not explain, f.e. it's the average money the company will pay to ALL opening positions? This way it is a weighted average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an **average**, so you should use a so-called *aggregation function* named `AVG`. However, to use an aggregation function, you must separate the table data into parts, and the average shall be calculated upon each part. You can do this with a `GROUP BY` expression (the parts are groups). Now you want to split the data among the companies, and the splitting criterion will be the `company name`.

Also, in MySQL if you have column names with spaces, you should wrap them in backticks.

```sql
SELECT `company name`, AVG(Hourly_Pay) as average_pay
FROM `job opening`
GROUP BY `company name`
```

Comment: so u basically added all the pay from each company and divided them by number of companies for average pay of each company?

Comment: If you have 10 total rows in the table and two  of the rows for company "Facebook" with Hourly_Pay 5.00 and 6.00 the result for "Facebook" will be `(5+6)/2 = 5.5`.

Comment: but the thing is that i have only got one entry/row for each company

Comment: You did not say that before, what guarantees that facebook will not have open positions for both "junior programmer" and "senior programmer"? That would be multiple rows for the same company.

Comment: Actually its a fixed table given to us for our assignments and we have to work with that 4 rows only

Comment: If you want to calculate the average hourly pay for EACH company separately AND the company name is unique, then the average would be always the same as the hourly rate, because you divide by 1 (count of rows with the same company name). this does does not make any sense.

Working on 4 specific rows does not make sense, you must create a general query.

You either don't understand the assignment or don't know how to explain it. Also, stack overflow is not for solving your assignment.

Comment: i think that is what the assignment wants..if  there is unique company, i should include only hourly rate for that company..thanks